# No me cargar pagina por php

Tags: php, javascript, html, html5, phpmyadmin

estoy tratando de cargar una pagina al momento que pase el control del login antes lo hacia pero ahora no la carga y no se que es les dejo el código.
Este es el código PHP

```html
<?php
 session_start();
 include ("conex.php");
 $usuario = $pass = "";
 $html = 0;
 if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){
  $usuario = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['user']);
  $pass = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['pwd']);
  $sql  = "SELECT id_congregacion, nombre_hermano, apellido_hermano FROM hermanos WHERE  user = '$usuario' AND pass = '$pass'";
  $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
  $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
  if (mysqli_num_rows($result) >= 1){
    $_SESSION['login_user'] = $row['nombre_hermano']." ".$row['apellido_hermano'];
    $_SESSION['congregacion'] = $row['id_congregacion'];
    header("Location: ../html/inicio.html");
    mysqli_free_result($result);
   }else{
      $html = 1;
   }
 } 
   echo $html;
   mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Código de conexión.

```html
<?php
 define ("DB_SERVER","localhost");
 define ("DB_USER_NAME","id4671277_root");
 define ("DB_PASSWORD","1234abcd");
 define ("DB_DATABASE","id4671277_controltajetas");
 $con = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER,DB_USER_NAME,DB_PASSWORD,DB_DATABASE);
 if (!$con){
  echo"Error: no se pudo conectar con MySQL." . PHP_EOL;
  echo "errno de depuración: " . mysqli_connect_errno() . PHP_EOL;
  echo "error de depuración: " . mysqli_connect_error() . PHP_EOL;
  exit;
 }
?>
```

Al realizar le prueba la variable $html me devuelve 0 lo que significa que encontró un dato y debería cargar la pagina de inicio les dejo unas imagenes para que vean que sale.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como pueden ver el carga el código pero no me visualiza la pagina, no se por que sucede esto, agradezco mucho su ayuda.

Comment: Revisar el fichero errors.log generado por el servidor te ayudará, sin duda, a encontrar el problema. Pues es un error generado en el lado del servidor.

Comment: ¿Revisaste el log de errores? En tu codigo se referencia la variable $con pero no se ve como se abre la conexion. Viendolo asi como esta

Comment: Disculpe pero como veo el log de errores del server soy nuevo en esto

Comment: El servidor apache tiene un archivo de configuracion llamado `httpd.conf`, este tiene un markup con la configuracion, para levantar la pagina seguramente tuviste que crear una directiva `<virtualHost>` en el. Adentro de ese tag veras una linea que dice `ErrorLog </el/log/>` ahi es donde se ubica el log de errores

Comment: Pero es que mi sitio lo en 000webhost de manera gratuita y antes este abria sin problema y no se por que ahora me genera este inconveniente

Comment: Oh, disculpa. Como era php intui que usabas apache, esa web te permite ver los logs desde su interfaz, tenes que ir a settings>logs.

Comment: De todas formas te recomendaria que para desarrollo utilices un servidor local en tu computadora, facilita mucho el trabajo

Comment: Gracias Sacha por el consejo de hecho así lo hago, pero estaba terminando de realizar unos ajustes y ahí fue donde ocurrió todo

Comment: Ya revise lo que me dijiste y no me sale nada extraordinario

Comment: Podrías añadir esta línea al principio del fichero para ver si te muestra algún error:    `error_reporting(E_ALL);`